# SSRS: Error while querying data from an Excel file (through ODBC)

Tags: excel, reporting-services, odbc, dsn

I am trying to render a simple chart using `SSRS`. The data is in an Excel sheet. I have set up an user DSN and created a data source in `SSRS` using `ODBC`.

I am able to query the excel in `Data` tab. However while trying to preview, I get the following error:

> error [hy000] [microsoft] [odbc excel driver] the connection for
>   viewing your linked Microsoft Excel worksheet was lost.

Anyone knows why this is happening and how this can be solved?

Answer (score 3):

I would consider creating a SQL Sever Integration Services package to import the data from Excel to a SQL database and using the database as the data source for the report. The SSIS package could be scheduled to periodically refresh the data. 
Using a file based data source like Excel is vulnerable to people modifying the structure of the spreadsheet and moving, deleting or locking the file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a fleeting error. I deleted the dataset, created a new one and re-ran again. It worked.